# Plotting and taking a moving average of a CSV data in java

Tags: java

This code is supposed to take a csv data and take the moving average of the data. Attached is the graph for the plot obtained in java. This plot is the same as the original plot. 
The goal is to get rid of all the data above the Pressure of 20 and also make it look more smoother like a square wave. But after I do the moving average, it still gives me the same graph. Also, how can I get rid of that spike between (0-50) seconds.
[image]
The moving average isn't working. There is something wrong with my moving average, but I can't figure it out. Please help. Thanks

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


public class MovinAverage {
    private static double freqS = 100.000;
    private static double sigma = 0.05;
    private static ArrayList<Double> noise = null;

    static ArrayList<Double> sec = null;
    private static double[] Pressure = new double[20481];
    private static ArrayList<Double> noisySignal = null;

    public static void recordVoice() throws NumberFormatException, IOException{
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\KwakuK\\Downloads\\smith2.csv")));     
        String currentLine = new String();
        currentLine = read.readLine();       
        double i = 0;
        //make some computation
        while((currentLine = read.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] numbers = currentLine.split(","); // split the string into sub strings
            if(numbers.length >= 3)
            {
                    System.out.println("currentLine: " + " " + currentLine);

            Pressure[(int) i++] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[2]); // when you do the 2, it's the third column which is the pressure

        }
    }

    }
    public static void setupFirstPlot() throws FileNotFoundException{

        sec = new ArrayList<Double>();
        double ws = 1/freqS;
        double n = (Pressure.length)*ws;

        for(double i = 0.01; i < n; i = i + ws){ 
            sec.add(i);
        }
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("plot3.csv"));
        for(int i = 0; i < Pressure.length; i++){
            pw.write(sec.get(i)+","+Pressure[i]+"\n");
        }
        pw.close();
    }

    public static double movingaverage(){
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Pressure.length; i++){
            sum +=Pressure[i];
        }
        double average = sum / Pressure.length;

    return average;

    }


    public static void setupNoisySignal(){
        noise = new ArrayList<Double>(Pressure.length);
        noisySignal = new ArrayList<Double>(Pressure.length);

        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < Pressure.length; i++){
            double value = rand.nextGaussian()*sigma;
            noise.add(value);
            noisySignal.add(value + Pressure[i]);
        }

    }

    public static void playSignal(ArrayList<Double> data) throws IOException{

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(byteStream);
            for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
                dataStream.writeDouble(data.get(i));
            }
            dataStream.close();
            byteStream.close();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        //Populate recording data and plotting data
        recordVoice();
        setupFirstPlot();
        setupNoisySignal();
        playSignal(noisySignal);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(movingaverage());

    }

}
```

Comment: What is "moving" about your moving average? And why do you start with `sum = 0.01`?

Comment: I don't get your first question. can you please rephrase it? It should be sum = 0. I will fix it. Thanks

Comment: Your method is called "moving average". This looks like it is calculating the average (specifically, the population mean). A moving average should be a series of data, which is the average calculated within a window that you slide across your data. In what sense does this method calculate a moving average?

Comment: I get it now. I really don't know how to go by doing the moving average. That's what I need help with. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A moving average is done over a given window. So you need to pass in that window to your average method (and use it). So in short you don't include all the data, you "forget" all the data that's past that window. So it's an average of the `windowLength` last data in the signal.

> a simple moving average (SMA) is the unweighted mean of the previous n data.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

```
public static double movingaverage(int windowLength) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = Math.max(0, Pressure.length-windowLength); i < Pressure.length; i++){
        sum += Pressure[i];
    }
    double average = sum / windowLength;

    return average;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to initialize my windowLength?

Comment: Yes although that is a requirement that I can't make up for you. It all depends on what your signal is and what whomever makes the requirements wants. For example, in finance, a classic moving average is the 30 days SMA. In that case, if your signal is 2 data points per day for example, then your window needs to be 60 to cover the 30 days. Again, it all depends on the nature of your signal and what they want you do to compute.

Comment: Yes, I got my windowlength initialize as private static double windowLength = 1600 but I'm still getting the same plot.

Comment: do you even have 1600 values in your signal?